# I can't install anything on Ubuntu 14.04 , kept saying "HASHSUM MISMATCH"?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, skype

Today I installed Ubuntu 14.04 . After that I tried to install Skype . But it gave the following error

```
E: Failed to fetch ht tp://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-4.8/libgcc-4.8-dev_4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
E: Failed to fetch ht tp://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-4.8/gcc-4.8_4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
E: Failed to fetch ht tp://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qt4-x11/libqtcore4_4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1_i386.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Even when i tried to execute sudo apt-get -f install it also gave me the error . What is the problem ? I tried all the possible solutions out there in the internet , but none of them worked . Did anyone face this kind of problem ? I even tried apt get-update . But even after updating it didn't work .

Comment: Read the error. Did you run "maybe run `apt-get update`" . Run `sudo apt-get update` and the output / error message if your problem persists.

Comment: Please read the question . I clearly mentioned that even after Running apt get-update it didn't work .

Comment: Read my comment, post the full output of your commands.

Comment: I updated the post @bodhi.zazen

Comment: @Pilot6 I even tried that . Still the same problem .

Comment: Try again later. The server is probably updating.

Comment: If it does not resolve you will have to file a bug report.